# Validator not being onboarded due to Election NoFallback error, possibly

Tags: consensus, election, private-network, validator

So my chain is running at the moment with 3 invulnerable validators, and I was trying to add another validator to the mix. I generated 2 accounts, transferred some stash to one of them, made a controller account, bonded some balance with the pair, set session keys and started the validation process, and I could see my stash under the waiting tab for staking. However on next session change, my validator was not included in the validator set, even though I had more stash than all invulnerables combined.

```
2022-03-07 14:16:57  New epoch 3 launching at block 0x951c…403f (block slot 548880939 >= start slot 548880939).    
2022-03-07 14:16:57  Next epoch starts at slot 548881139    
2022-03-07 14:16:57 [#594]   Entering emergency mode: ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")    
2022-03-07 14:16:57 [594]  election provider failed due to ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")
```

[image]
I repeatedly get these messages on each session/era change. How can I fix this?

EDIT : Steps I've tried before :

1. Made sure

```
type Fallback = frame_election_provider_support::onchain::OnChainSequentialPhragmen<Self>;
```

2. Started 3 nodes with invulnerable accounts, `--offchain-worker always`
3. The only thing missing from my runtime code is an implementation of `frame_system::offchain::CreateSignedTransaction<LocalCall>` but I don't know how relevant it is.

After running with `-lruntime::election-provider=trace,runtime::staking=trace`, most particularly @ block #200 we can see this line :

```
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#200]   closed signed phase, found solution? false, discarded 0
```

Here's the full logs running upto the NoFallback emergency phase ->

```
2022-03-08 22:32:18.033  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #149 (0xa76d…cede)    
2022-03-08 22:32:18.033 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#149]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Signed    
2022-03-08 22:32:21.006 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#150]   current phase Signed, next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:32:21.007  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #150 (0xbe66…165e)    
2022-03-08 22:32:21.007 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#150]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Signed    
2022-03-08 22:32:22.050  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (3 peers), best: #150 (0xbe66…165e), finalized #147 (0xdd44…31f2), ⬇ 3.6kiB/s ⬆ 3.1kiB/s    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.030 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   current phase Signed, next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.030 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   closed signed phase, found solution? false, discarded 0    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.031  INFO tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   Starting unsigned phase round 1 enabled true.    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.039  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #151 (0xb006…6828)    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.044 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.044 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   miner attempting to compute an unsigned solution.    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.044 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   from 5 assignments, truncating to 5 for weight, removing 0    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.044 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   from 5 assignments, truncating to 5 for length, removing 0    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.044 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   pre-dispatch checks failed for mined solution: Module { index: 19, error: 1, message: Some("PreDispatchWrongWinnerCount") }    
2022-03-08 22:32:24.044 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#151]   initial offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::PreDispatchChecksFailed(Module { index: 19, error: 1, message: Some("PreDispatchWrongWinnerCount") }))    
2022-03-08 22:32:27.021 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#152]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:32:27.022  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #152 (0x011d…36a6)    
2022-03-08 22:32:27.022 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#152]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:32:27.022 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#152]   resubmit offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::Lock("recently executed."))    
2022-03-08 22:32:27.050  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (3 peers), best: #152 (0x011d…36a6), finalized #149 (0xa76d…cede), ⬇ 3.4kiB/s ⬆ 2.9kiB/s    
2022-03-08 22:32:30.010 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#153]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:32:30.011  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #153 (0x5096…6bcf)    
2022-03-08 22:32:30.012 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#153]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:32:30.012 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#153]   resubmit offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::Lock("recently executed."))
```

and then a few moments later :

```
2022-03-08 22:34:12.011 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #187 (0x59cd…e4be)    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   miner attempting to restore or compute an unsigned solution.    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   restoring solution failed due to MinerError::NoStoredSolution    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   mining a new solution.    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   from 5 assignments, truncating to 5 for weight, removing 0    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   from 5 assignments, truncating to 5 for length, removing 0    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   pre-dispatch checks failed for mined solution: Module { index: 19, error: 1, message: Some("PreDispatchWrongWinnerCount") }    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.012 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#187]   resubmit offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::PreDispatchChecksFailed(Module { index: 19, error: 1, message: Some("PreDispatchWrongWinnerCount") }))    
2022-03-08 22:34:12.057  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (3 peers), best: #187 (0x59cd…e4be), finalized #184 (0x75df…d3af), ⬇ 3.7kiB/s ⬆ 2.9kiB/s    
2022-03-08 22:34:15.006 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#188]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:15.008  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #188 (0xafb7…bb43)    
2022-03-08 22:34:15.008 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#188]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:34:15.008 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#188]   resubmit offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::Lock("recently executed."))    
2022-03-08 22:34:15.009 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#188]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:15.010  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #188 (0xb7ff…5594)    
2022-03-08 22:34:17.057  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (3 peers), best: #188 (0xafb7…bb43), finalized #186 (0x02f0…384f), ⬇ 3.5kiB/s ⬆ 3.0kiB/s    
2022-03-08 22:34:18.027 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#189]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:18.032  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #189 (0x6f4b…5fc5)    
2022-03-08 22:34:18.032 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#189]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:34:18.032 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#189]   resubmit offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::Lock("recently executed."))    
2022-03-08 22:34:21.010 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#190]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:21.011  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #190 (0x15e6…0e33)    
2022-03-08 22:34:21.011 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#190]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:34:21.012 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#190]   resubmit offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::Lock("recently executed."))    
2022-03-08 22:34:22.058  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (3 peers), best: #190 (0x15e6…0e33), finalized #187 (0x59cd…e4be), ⬇ 3.4kiB/s ⬆ 2.9kiB/s    
2022-03-08 22:34:24.011 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#191]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:24.013  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #191 (0x2901…8d21)    
2022-03-08 22:34:24.013 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#191]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:34:24.013 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#191]   resubmit offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::Lock("recently executed."))
```

And finally :

```
2022-03-08 22:34:48.028 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.033  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #199 (0x74af…b9a4)    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.033 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Unsigned((true, 151))    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.034 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   miner attempting to restore or compute an unsigned solution.    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.034 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   restoring solution failed due to MinerError::NoStoredSolution    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.034 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   mining a new solution.    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.034 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   from 5 assignments, truncating to 5 for weight, removing 0    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.034 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   from 5 assignments, truncating to 5 for length, removing 0    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.034 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   pre-dispatch checks failed for mined solution: Module { index: 19, error: 1, message: Some("PreDispatchWrongWinnerCount") }    
2022-03-08 22:34:48.034 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   resubmit offchain thread output: Err(MinerError::PreDispatchChecksFailed(Module { index: 19, error: 1, message: Some("PreDispatchWrongWinnerCount") }))    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe:  New epoch 1 launching at block 0xa828…43a0 (block slot 548919697 >= start slot 548919697).    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012  INFO tokio-runtime-worker babe:  Next epoch starts at slot 548919897    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#200]   current phase Unsigned((true, 151)), next election 201, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::staking: [200]  ending session 0    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::staking: [200]  starting session 1    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::staking: [200]  planning new session 2    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#200]   closed signed phase, found solution? false, discarded 0    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#200]   Entering emergency mode: ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.012  WARN tokio-runtime-worker runtime::staking: [200]  election provider failed due to ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.014  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #200 (0xa828…43a0)    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.014 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#200]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Emergency    
2022-03-08 22:34:51.014 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#200]   clearing offchain call cache storage.    
2022-03-08 22:34:52.059  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (3 peers), best: #200 (0xa828…43a0), finalized #198 (0xf785…a574), ⬇ 3.5kiB/s ⬆ 3.2kiB/s    
2022-03-08 22:34:54.011 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#201]   current phase Emergency, next election 401, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })    
2022-03-08 22:34:54.012  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #201 (0xd142…5747)    
2022-03-08 22:34:54.012 TRACE      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#201]   lock for offchain worker acquired. Phase = Emergency    
2022-03-08 22:34:57.012 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime::election-provider: [#202]   current phase Emergency, next election 401, metadata: Some(SolutionOrSnapshotSize { voters: 5, targets: 4 })
```

Comment: What is the `ValidatorCount` set too? Also can you at the logging flags `-lruntime::election-provider=trace,runtime::staking=trace`

Comment: @zekemostov Do you mean the validator_count in Staking genesis config? That's set to 255 in this chain.

Comment: Can you please explain this logging command? I am afraid I only see logs like `offchain-worker` from elections_multi_phase and no staking logs.

Comment: @zekemostov I've added the logs in the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

> `2022-03-08 22:34:48.034 DEBUG      offchain-worker runtime::election-provider: [#199]   pre-dispatch checks failed for mined solution: Module { index: 19, error: 1, message: Some("PreDispatchWrongWinnerCount") }`

This reveals that the underlying issue is the same as explained in a [similar question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/651/substrate-validators-losing-connection-to-each-other/676#676):

> The reason for the failure can be multiple things, but the most common one is that you don't have enough validators candidates, compared to how many you want.
> In other words, if you check the storage item `Staking::validator_count`, and for example if this value is 4, but you only have 3 candidates, your election will always fail.

The same fix as suggested there should work for you as well.

Comment: Just to reiterate in more concrete terms, set `validator_count` to 3, add the new validator and then increase `validator_count` to 4.

Comment: Alright I will be applying this fix. But in general are these types of errors recoverable? I don't have a clue how this would pan out on a production chain.

Comment: This how you recover from this on a real chain: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/index.html#emergency-phase