# Substrate validators election failing and connectivy lost

Tags: runtime, election

Hey so I have been running a custom substrate chain with 3 validators.
But recently the chain got crashed with a log
 `election provider failed due to ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")`

But the chain continued to run after getting this error in chain and in the explorer
`stakingElectionfailed`

But after some time the peers connected to validators went from 2 to 0. And when I checked the logs, the validators started forking each other and lost the connectivity.

Trying to debug this. Anyone faced any similar issue or any hints that I can use? I'm stuck nowhere now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because for some reason your `pallet-election-provider-multi-phase` failed, without a proper fallback configured. The reason for the failure can be multiple things, but the most common one is that you don't have enough validators candidates, compared to how many you want.

In other words, if you check the storage item `Staking::validator_count`, and for example if this value is 4, but you only have 3 candidates, your election will always fail.

We are working on relaxing this condition in [this pull request](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10905).

The easiest fix for a failing election, specially for test networks, is to change `type Fallback` to something that doesn't fail as easy. An example of this is [`frame_election_provider_support::OnchainSequentialPhragmen`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_election_provider_support/onchain/struct.OnChainSequentialPhragmen.html).

Although, using this in production can be problematic. This is also something that [another pull request](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10988) is trying to tackle.

Comment: hey thanks @kianenigma! actually the onchainphragmen was not properly configured and it worked fixing that. 

A doubt on my mind is that before losing connectivity with each other the validators in my case its 3(```validator_count``` is also put as 3) has creatde a fork and when I checked the logs each have different extrisics. So the reason I'm thinking is that on the next epoc change the ```im-online```  was not working and no fallback configured so validators were not selected correctly?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isn't that the job for `minimum_validator_count`? If election will fail for validators < `validator_count` doesn't it invalidate the reason for existence of `minimum_validator_count`?